# function parameter is undefined in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Why function **CarName** parameter passing as **undefined**, Why actual value not retrieving?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.carname = "Honda";

    $scope.SaveData = function (carname) {

        console.log('Car Name='+carname);

    };
})
```

Comment: please show how you are calling function here car name should come as parameter when you are calling the function

Comment: <button ng-click="SaveData(carname)">Save</button>

Comment: calling on a button click  <button ng-click="SaveData()">Save</button>

Comment: then pass parameter while calling like this
 <button ng-click="SaveData(carname )">Save</button>

Comment: am not binding carname in ng-model

Comment: then also it will work provided your button is in myCtrl controller scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this working demo

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="SaveData(carname )">Save</button>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.carname = "Honda";
    $scope.SaveData = function (carname) {
        alert(carname)
        console.log('Car Name='+carname);
    };
 })
```

check here http://codepen.io/vkvicky-vasudev/pen/XjkZBN

if you are trying to use object

```
var obj = [{ name: "Honda", Year: 2016 }]; // then simply do like this

$scope.SaveData = function () {
    alert(carname)
    console.log('Car Name=' + obj);
};
```

or if you want scope variable then

```
$scope.obj = [{ name: "Honda", Year: 2016 }]; // then simply do like this

$scope.SaveData = function () {
    alert(carname)
    console.log('Car Name=' + $scope.obj);
};
```

Comment: Hi Vicky, Thank you. But i don't want to pass carname as SaveData(carname) ,can we do without passing parameter from ng-click ?

Comment: becuase i want to pass Json object var obj=[{name:'Honda", Year:2016}];

Comment: @ShakeerHussain if you dont want to pass parameter while calling function then why you are trying to accept parameter in function definition you simply use scope variable no need of parameter in function use like this  


      $scope.SaveData = function () {

        console.log('Car Name='+$scope.carname);

    };

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have function here, if you are not binding data to the ui on some event,

You can just use `$scope.carname` ,

```
 console.log('Car Name='+$scope.carname);
```

Comment: Hello Sajeetharan. $scope,carname Its not working .Throwing error

Comment: You should use  $scope.carname  not  $scope,carname

Comment: @ShakeerHussain why dont you use $scope.carname instead of passing to a function

Answer (score 0):

Yes, No parameter is required.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.carname = "Honda";

    $scope.SaveData = function () {

        console.log('Car Name='+carname);

    };
})
```

Comment: its better to mark as answer rather than forming a new answer

Comment: @Shakeer this suggestion is already provided in two different answer there is no difference in yours that two came after you discussed and you didnt agreed and marked answer as not helpful and finally using same concept